# What's the shortcut key to access the sign "/" on keyboard Lenovo Ideapad?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

What's the shortcut key to access the sign "/" on keyboard? My notebook is a Lenovo Ideapad.

Comment: Should be on the Keyboard. Which kind of Ideapad do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding onto Horatio's answer, to access the `/` key on your keyboard, it's typically under the Q. To press that key, you must use the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> right next to the <kbd>Win Key</kbd>.

Take a look at the picture in horatio's answer and use that as a reference.

You must press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to get the `/`.

Answer (score 3):

Your account mentions brasil, and according to this image:

[image: http://frontype.com/keyboarding/540px-Computer-keyboard-Portuguese-Brazil.svg.png]

The '/' key is in two places: below the `Q` using a function key (upper left), and on the same key as the '?' beside the right `shift` key. Note also that the right-hand `ALT` key is color-coded blue, the same as the `/` under the `Q`